# glympse client sdk sample - failed to create error message

Tags: android, glympse

I am using the examples from https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/client-sdk/downloads link.

I tried the `GlympseSendDemo` and `GlympseCreateDemo` using Android Studio(without any changes apart from editing the temporary developer API key that I created by creating an account online).

When I run both examples, I get a

> "Failed to create"

message. What could be wrong with this?

---

**EDIT 1**

Debugging both the samples, the `_glympse` member is null when it hits the breakpoint i set at `createGlympse()` method of `GlympseWrapper` class.

**EDIT 2**

The `GE.PLATFORM_STOPPED` event from the Glympse SDK is getting fired that causes the `_glympse` variable to be set to null through the call `GlympseWrapper.instance().clear();`.

So my question is why is this event getting fired within a few seconds of the app starting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a breakpoint in GlympseWrapper.clear(). I suspect the platform is stopping after starting causing _glympse to be set to null. If that's happening, double check the api key is entered correctly.

```
_glympse = GlympseFactory.createGlympse(context, BASE_URL, API_KEY);

// Also try adding this line here to get some additional log information
_glympse.overrideLoggingLevels(CoreConstants.INFO, CoreConstants.INFO);
```

Comment: Note for self and others who might find this helpful: the `CoreConstants` are found in package `com.glympse.android.core.CoreConstants` . Do a search for the class name [here](https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/client-sdk/reference/android/index) to get the package information specific to android. Google might lead to several other links such as [this](http://dgc.glympse.com/Content/client/full/wp/reference/CoreConstants.html) which is windows specific.